# How to make Log4J2 working in JBoss EAP 6.4

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, log4j, log4j2

I have seen successful instance online to make Log4J2 works in JBoss EAP 6.x

My local war file has specific situation (JBoss EAP 6.4, JDK8):

1. The war is built on Spring 3 framework, where most logging is made by `Apache Common Logging`
2. Logging of the source code in the war is made by `Slf4J`
3. However, some in house dependencies in `WEB-INF/lib` is still made by `Log4J 1.2`, not `slf4J`

So I added following dependency to the project, listed below (only list the jar file instead of verbose pom xml):

```
### spring framework from jcl to slf4j
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar

### slf4j to log4j 1.2 then to log4j2
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar
log4j-1.2-api-2.11.1.jar

### slf4j to log4j 2
slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar
log4j-api-2.8.2.jar
log4j-core-2.8.2.jar
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.jar
```

My plan is to tell EAP 6.4 to never use any logging module from JBoss, instead just use whatever is provided from this war, so in the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` I create following elements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="oracle" />
        </dependencies>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name='org.slf4j.impl' />
            <module name='org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j' />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

And when the application starts, I can see following information show up in the server log, extracted here

```
Adding resource "/C:/Windows/content/MyApp.war/WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar" to module deployment.MyApp.war:main

Adding resource "/C:/Windows/content/MyApp.war/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar" to module deployment.MyApp.war:main
Adding resource "/C:/Windows/content/MyApp.war/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar" to module deployment.MyApp.war:main
Adding resource "/C:/Windows/content/MyApp.war/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar" to module deployment.MyApp.war:main

Adding resource "/C:/Windows/content/MyApp.war/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2-api-2.11.1.jar" to module deployment.MyApp.war:main
Adding resource "/C:/Windows/content/MyApp.war/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.8.2.jar" to module deployment.MyApp.war:main
Adding resource "/C:/Windows/content/MyApp.war/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.8.2.jar" to module deployment.MyApp.war:main
Adding resource "/C:/Windows/content/MyApp.war/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.jar" to module deployment.MyApp.war:main
```

there is not much further information regarding logging in the server log, no error.

However no matter how I configure the log appender (`ROL` or `Console`), there is no log4J log generated. I use FileAppender but there is no log file generated.

I don't think it is caused by log4J configuration issue, because same war file with the same log4J2.xml the logging output fine in `Tomcat 8`

How can I make this right so at least the application output logging successfully.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple SLF4J bindings in your dependencies:

1. slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar
2. slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar
3. log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.jar

**Action 1:** Remove slf4j-simple and choose one of [slf4j-log4j12](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/tree/v_1.7.25/slf4j-log4j12/src/main/java/org/slf4j/impl) or [log4j-slf4j-impl](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/tree/log4j-2.8.2/log4j-slf4j-impl/src/main/java/org/slf4j/impl).

Beside that, TWO API dependencies for log4j look suspicious:

1. log4j-1.2-api-2.11.1.jar
2. log4j-api-2.8.2.jar

**Action 2:** Remove log4j-1.2-api-2.11.1.jar since you use implementation version 2.8.2 of log4j.

Comment: Thank you. I tried both actions but still no log generated

Comment: It looks like log4j-slf4j-impl and slf4j-log4j12 both provide bindings as well. Answer updated.